# Summary of GCC option -ftime-report for entire project

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake

I have a large C++ project of hundreds of files with a CMake build system. How can I use GCC's `-ftime-report` option but get a single summary for the full build?

I am looking to improve build times and this would be helpful to know where to focus the effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to implement that manually by parsing the output somehow.

A good way to get a higher level overview is to use Ninja and parse the .ninja_log file:
https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/issues/1080#issuecomment-255436851

Also see https://github.com/nico/ninjatracing. Chromium uses tools like that to keep track of build times.

Update:

`-ftime-report` is simply not suitable for this task as it's meant for compiler devs. Use clang and https://github.com/aras-p/ClangBuildAnalyzer for this.

gcc is far from supporting `-ftime-trace`: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=92396

Comment: Accepting this answer even if it's only partial because it's the best we've got for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Per @Trass3r's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53349175), gcc's `-ftime-report` isn't helpful for most developers. There is a very useful gcc plug-in that will give *per-file* information, see below, but nothing that I'm aware of like the combination of clang's built-in `-ftime-trace` with [Clang Analyzer](https://github.com/aras-p/ClangBuildAnalyzer). While I do find it useful to run Clang Analyzer and fix any issues identified across the whole build, all too often the correlation between clang build-time and gcc turns out to be quite low, and my gcc build is only marginally faster.

What I do to drill into gcc problems is

- remove the ninja log
- clean build
- use [ninja tracing](https://github.com/nico/ninjatracing) to transform the log to json
- load the log into [perfetto](https://ui.perfetto.dev)

  - run a query like `select name, ts/1000000 start, dur/1000000 t from slice order by t DESC` to see the longest compiles
  - and use the visualization to check there's no long tail, or suspicious "gaps" when processors aren't being used.

Then for any unusually long compiles, use the excellent [externis gcc plug-in](https://github.com/royjacobson/externis) to get per-file data. Again, you can load the resulting json into perfetto.

In CMake you can use a cache variable to drive the different approaches for clang and gcc

```
  option(TIME_TRACE "Time trace")

  if(TIME_TRACE)
    if(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
      add_compile_options(-ftime-trace)
    elseif(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "GNU")
      # gcc: use plugin https://github.com/royjacobson/externis
      add_compile_options(-fplugin=/PATH/TO/externis.so) # or install it, see docs
    endif()
  endif()
```